# How to predict average Y from averages of X for GLM Quasi-poisson regression?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

Need some help from the community :)

**Data and Task Description**

I have the data in following form:

| Y | X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 10 |
| 2 | 1500 | 200 |
| 1 | 1000 | 110 |

Y - is the target variable I'm trying to predict. That is the number of office visits.

X1 - is the amount of cash a customer has, X2 - is the number of bank transactions customer made.

I have a matrix of data, where one row corresponds to one client. So one row - one client. And I have several thousands of rows for a particular period.

I used Poisson regression (quasi-poisson), and now have the equation let's say

```
log(Y) = 1.5 + 0.3*X1 + 0.5*X2
```

The model works quite good, I tested that on the held-out dataset.

**Problem**

Now, I have a bunch of new data. But I'm not allowed just to score clients using my regression equation.
Instead I have only descriptive statistics for X1 and X2 (mean, median, percentiles, variances).
I also know the size of a new sample.

My task is to assess the total number of visits (e.g. sum(Y)) for that new sample given only descriptive statistics of X1 and X2 and the size of the sample.

So in general I want to know is there a way to calculate the mean(Y) given mean(X1), mean (X2) and poisson regression coefficients estimated.

In case of linear regression it would be absolutely correct just to plug in mean(X1) and mean(X2) in regression equation and then multiply by the sample size, however in case of non-linear regression I have no idea of what can be done.

Are there any solutions?